# git push "src refspec refs/heads/feature/a-feature-branch does not match any"

Tags: git, push, git-push, git-flow

After a git flow command for finishing a feature branch **git flow feature finish a-feature-branch**, the **git push -v** command always gives me the following error msg, no matter the branch I am.

```
Pushing to git@github.com:/repo/repo.git
error: src refspec refs/heads/feature/a-feature-branch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:/repo/repo.git'
```

Everything worked fine with the finish feature command, so it does not seems to be a problem with **git flow**.

If I manually sets the remote and branch name, it works, eg.:

```
git push origin develop
```

It seems like git push is trying to push the deleted branch, like something is dirty with it's references. I've searched and tried a lot of things, but it seems that this old reference never give up.

It's not a new repository and every branch I'm trying to commit exists on remote. Past **push** and **feature finish** commands worked fine. The same thing happened with two other computers.

Comment: This sounds like it is a bug (albeit minor) in `git flow` (I don't use `git flow` myself and cannot be sure about this). What is your `push.default` setting and which version of Git are you running?

Comment: @torek, my `push.default` is `simple`. I'm using git version 2.7.4 and git flow 1.9.1 (AVH Edition). I will update my git and see what happens.

Comment: Updated git to 2.18.0 and still the same. I image that by recreating the repository it will come back to normal, but I'm really curious to know what is causing the problem, what configuration is wrong.

Comment: OK, definitely sounds like a `git flow` bug. Those defaults seem fine, and even 2.7.x is not *that* ancient (not exactly new) but now you have 2.18 anyway...